# How to grab an HTML element within my Angular component and apply an event listener to it?

Tags: angular, dom

I want to access an html element in my Angular component and add an event listener to it. However, when I use querySelector to grab the html element, I get a null value instead.

Here is the burger class I want to get:

```
<div class="burger">
 <div class="line-1"></div>
 <div class="line-2"></div>
 <div class="line-3"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my component ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavBarService } from '../../shared/services/nav-bar.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../shared/services/auth.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-nav-bar',
templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.css']
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public nav: NavBarService,
            public authService: AuthService,
           ) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.nav.show();

  const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('nav-links');

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => { 
   nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
     });
    }
   }
  navSlide();
 }
```

When the the application compiles, I get the error "cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null."

Comment: You can find different ways of accessing HTML element from component in angular with little search.

Comment: Can you add some more context or code so others can determine your intent behind what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question so it was more specific.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic?

Comment: @KariF. At the time it was closed, it was off-topic because it was asking to debug code that wasn't in the question. That's been remedied, but it takes time for the system to realize it should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add event listeners manually. Just use the angular way:

HTML:

```
<div (click)="yourFunctionName($event)"></div>
```

Typescript:

```
yourFunctionName(event: any) {
  alert('Clicked!');
}
```

See the guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewChild** with #localvariable as shown here,

```
<textarea  #variable id="tasknote"
                  name="tasknote"
                  [(ngModel)]="taskNote"
                  placeholder="{{ notePlaceholder }}"
                  style="background-color: pink"
                  (blur)="updateNote() ; noteEditMode = false " (click)="noteEditMode = false"> {{ todo.note }} 

</textarea>
```

in component

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('variable') el:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
   this.el.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Here is the queryselector code snippet:

```
constructor (private _elementRef : elementRef) {
 this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('textarea').focus();
 }
```